# Where do I put the mapping files for Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am confused by the ES docs, in fact [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/conf-mappings/) they state the the indexes must go in the mapping dir (and indexname sub dirs):

> Mappings can be defined within files called [mapping_name].json and be
>   placed either under config/mappings/_default location, or under
>   config/mappings/[index_name] (for mappings that should be associated
>   only with a specific index).

But then [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-templates/) in the "config" section, it states:

> Index templates can also be placed within the config location
>   (path.conf) under the templates directory (note, make sure to place
>   them on all master eligible nodes). For example, a file called
>   template_1.json can be placed under config/templates and it will be
>   added if it matches an index.

I put my mapping in `/config/mappings/myindexname/mappinfile.json` and it is like:

```
{
    "template": "maincontentindex",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "htmlStrippingAnalyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": ["standard", "lowercase"],
                        "char_filter": "html_strip"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "mappings": {
        "rendition": {
            "_timestamp": {
                "enabled": true,
                "store" : true
            },
            "properties": {
                "key": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "parentPage": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "language": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "device": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "territory": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "channel": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "template": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "meta": {
                    "properties": {
                        "content": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": "yes"
                        }
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I use the REST Api to put it in the server it works fine and if I call /maincontentindex/rendition/_mapping I just get the above structure (even with no data).

But with the directory I just get a 404 and if I insert anything it's just the usual dynamic mapping.

Comment: Ftr: (at least) [as of ES 5.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-conf-mappings.html) "It is no longer possible to specify mappings in files in the config directory. Instead, mappings should be created using the API". I strongly assume the same goes for templates.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a difference between mappings and templates.

[Mappings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/) contain your fields and how you want to index/store them in elasticsearch. They refer to a specific index and type (or multiple types in the same index when using the `_default_` special type). You can submit mappings either while creating an index through the [create index api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-create-index/), or through the [put mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/) to modify the mappings for an existing index.

[Index templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-templates/) are a way to automatically apply mappings and index settings to indices that are going to be created in the future, whose names match a specified pattern. Let's say that mappings are a part of an index template. An index template can contains mappings for multiple types and index settings too.

If you have an index template, you can put it under `templates` as mentioned in the reference. If you have a mapping for a type, you need to put it under the `mappings` directory.

The json that you pasted into the question is an index template, which needs to go under the `templates` folder, not under the `mappings` one. What you get back using the get mapping api as described is not the template itself as you said but the current mapping for the index/type that you specified in the url (only the mappings part of your template).

Also, I would suggest you to use the REST api that elasticsearch provides. Using files on file system doesn't really look like the elasticsearch way of doing things.

Comment: while I was waiting for the answer I worked that out alread :) only one thing doesn't work... when writing a mapping, where do I put the settings section?

Comment: Settings don't fit in the mappings :) You have to use the update settings api separately. I'm not aware of a place where you can put the index settings on file system. I would then use index templates which can contain both mappings and settings.

Comment: I ended up doing it. Grazie!

Comment: Why is using files discouraged ? having configuration files is way easier for automated deployment and version control, also easy to read off the current configuration by opening a file in a text editor. I'm always wondering how many people do with only rest APIs with elasticsearch. When deploying a new cluster with known configuration, how do you use REST API to set your configuration ?