# Defining mapping within elasticsearch with json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a json file to define the default mapping for each index. This is what I am trying to do:

**/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/default-mapping.json**

```
{
    "item": {
        "properties": {
            "uuid": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "index": "no"},
            "title": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "boost": 5,
                      "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "english"},
            "description": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "boost": 3,
                            "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "english"},
}
```

When I try and query my index_test elasticsearch index I get this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://...:9200/index_test/_mapping'
{"index_test":{"mappings":{}}}
```

I used the documentation found on here.

https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-mapping-introduction/

Comment: This one will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855318/where-do-i-put-the-mapping-files-for-elasticsearch

Comment: @Rob Thank you for the reply, and I did see that before, but I'm not sure how it will help me

Answer (score 3):

You can create [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#config) with default configuration(index settings, mapping etc) for your indices.

1. To do this, change content of default-mapping.json file to something
   like:

   ```
   {
       "template_1" : {
           "template" : "*",
           "mappings" : {
               "type" : {
                   "properties" : {
                       "uuid" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "store" : "yes",
                           "index" : "no"
                       },
                       "title" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "store" : "yes",
                           "boost" : 5,
                           "index" : "analyzed",
                           "analyzer" : "english"
                       },
                       "description" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "store" : "yes",
                           "boost" : 3,
                           "index" : "analyzed",
                           "analyzer" : "english"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Move default-mapping.json file to
   /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/templates directory
3. Create a new index

   ```
   POST /newindex
   ```
4. Mapping of newly created index:

   ```
   {
       "newindex" : {
           "mappings" : {
               "type" : {
                   "properties" : {
                       "description" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "boost" : 3,
                           "store" : true,
                           "analyzer" : "english"
                       },
                       "title" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "boost" : 5,
                           "store" : true,
                           "analyzer" : "english"
                       },
                       "uuid" : {
                           "type" : "string",
                           "index" : "no",
                           "store" : true
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have create the index `index_test` already, you need to execute the following (as in your link):

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index_test/my_type/_mapping' -d '
{
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "uuid": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "no"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "boost": 5,
        "index": "analyzed",
        "analyzer": "english"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "boost": 3,
        "index": "analyzed",
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}

'
```

The important bit is to note that the field in the payload corresponds to the type-name (generically I took my_type).

Verify with a `GET` on `url:9200/index_test/_mapping/my_type?pretty`.

regards
fricke

Comment: Really good answer. I would like to add one thing. You might not find templates directory into elasticsearch/config. You should create one and put your mapping file into it.

Answer (score 0):

your JSON document is not valid. it should be :

```
{
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "uuid": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "index": "no"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "boost": 5,
                "index": "analyzed",
                "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "boost": 3,
                "index": "analyzed",
                "analyzer": "english"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i advise you to always check your JSON documents when you modify your mapping.
ElasticSearch will just ignore your mapping and not prompt you any error when  you send a non valid JSON document as mapping

JSON validator site: http://jsonlint.com/